# Retrieving authentication info for a JBoss webservice

Tags: jboss, service

I have a webservice with basic HTTP authentication on a JBoss server. Is there a way to retrieve the authentication credentials (username, pw) supplied by the caller from within the webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the HTTP headers?  There should be an "Authorization" header that indicates that Basic Authentication was used.  It should also include a Base64-encoded String representing the username/password.

Comment: How would I check the HTTP headers from the web service on the server side? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Got it working:

https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/articles/MessageContext.html
http://community.jboss.org/message/338026#338026

For web services, you'll need to use MessageContext and the @Resource annotation to have access to additional metadata parameters not included in SOAP message calls. 

The links above make it pretty straightforward. 

The username and password are stored as a colon-delimited value in 64bit encoding in the "authorization" header, for BASIC authentication only